# Radial Gradient Styling

Tags: css, gradient

Quick question:

How would you stylize a radial gradient within CSS to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the point in removing the link and not leaving any clue what the question was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jsfiddle link: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmWpc/)**

Html code:

```
<div class="gradient">
</div>
```

Css code:

```
.gradient{ height:79px; 
width:298px; 
background: #7ddbfb; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7ddbfb 46%, #56bdf4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(46%,#7ddbfb), color-stop(100%,#56bdf4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7ddbfb 46%,#56bdf4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7ddbfb 46%,#56bdf4 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #7ddbfb 46%,#56bdf4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #7ddbfb 46%,#56bdf4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7ddbfb', endColorstr='#56bdf4',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

You can try making gradients **[Here](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)**